Delete a row in Google Sheets macro function
I am basically trying to trying to have a function that will delete a row if column "D" date has passed so it can update every morning
So far I have
function UntitledMacro() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('A2:G185').activate()
  .sort([{column: 4, ascending: true}, {column: 1, ascending: true}, {column: 5, ascending: true}]);
}

Is what I am currently using very simple lol which works for sorting, but would like to add the additional functions.



Timestamp
Email Address
Name: Last, First
Select what dates you will be available to be called:
What shift?
Preferred method of contact:
Contact phone number




11/17/2024 19:54:58
Randomemail@gmail.com
Doe, John
11/16/2024
Day Shift
Text
385-123-4568


11/14/2024 16:30:38
Randomemail@gmail.com
Doe, Jane
11/17/2024
Night Shift
Call
385-123-4568



function deleteCompletedRow() {
const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
const sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
const sheetData = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
const sheetDataHeaders = sheetData[0];
for (let i = sheetData.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
if (sheetData[i][sheetDataHeaders.indexOf("Detail")] == "Completed") {
    sheet.deleteRow(i + 1);
}

^Is what I imported from the recommended link, if I switched the header to "Detail" and fill in the column with completed it also does not delete it, it sorts it to the bottom, but that could be because I need to add it before the other function?

Welcome to Stack Overlow. The question is unclear. Please ensure that the question concerns a specific practical problem unique to programming and ensure that the title properly summaries what was said in the question body.

Ya sorry about that, I am basically trying to trying to have a function that will delete a row if column "D" date has passed so it can update every morning.

Please [edit] the question to focus on that.

Updated, thank you.

Please checkout Deleting rows in google sheets using Google Apps Script

This question is similar to: Auto delete Rows with dates older than today. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem. Please make use of the comment as it also handles your question about updating it every morning.

@Babanana appreciate it, I am very new to this do I just literally copy and paste it into the macro script and be good?

That is really depending on what your data looks like. Though it is really a good basis for your question, how easy it is to integrate an existing code to your project will depend on the situation which is dictated by your data set. Can you post a plain text table how your data looks like?

Can you put this on your Posted Question so it will be readable, make sure that codes are properly formatted

My aplogies this is all updated and hopefully readable at this point.

You want to delete rows where the date in Column D is less than today's date.
Consider this answer:

var today = new Date() - gets today's date
for (var r=(+sheetData.length-1);r>0;r--){ - loop through the data from bottom to top so that the index number isn't disrupted
var shiftDate = sheetData[r][3] - this is the value in Column D
if (shiftDate.valueOf() < today.valueOf()) { - uses valueOf (Date.prototype.valueOf()) to compare the shift date with today's date.
sheet.deleteRow(+r+1) - deletes the row

deleteRow deletes a given row number, as opposed to the variable "r" which is a zero-based array value. So "add 1" to get the row to delete.




function deleteOldRows() {
  var  ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var sheetData = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  console.log("length of sheetdata = "+sheetData.length)
  var today = new Date()

  // loop through the rows from bottom to top
  for (var r=(+sheetData.length-1);r>0;r--){
    var shiftDate = sheetData[r][3]
    //Logger.log("row = "+r+", the date = "+shiftDate+", value = "+shiftDate.valueOf())

    if (shiftDate.valueOf() < today.valueOf()) {
      Logger.log("delete this row"+"row = "+r+", the date = "+shiftDate+", value = "+shiftDate.valueOf())
      sheet.deleteRow(+r+1);
    }else{
      Logger.log("dont delete this row"+"row = "+r+", the date = "+shiftDate+", value = "+shiftDate.valueOf())
    }
  }
}


SAMPLE - before


SAMPLE - after


